# Creating map booklets or flyers (not mapbooks)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, printing, layouts

I'm wondering if there is existing extensions or add-ons for ArcGIS 10.1 where I can create more sophisticated printable maps. I'm aware of datadriven pages and mapbooks, but I'm looking for something that's more like a booklet or a folded pamphlet  that would be given away at say a tourism booth. I'd like to have separate pages for a legend and map (or different "panels"). Ideally, this would be integrated into ArcGIS so that as points change the legend would update as well. I'm aware I could do this within ArcGIS with some clever measuring - but what if I wanted to print double sided all in one go?

So far I've found this:

[MapLogic Layout Manager](http://www.maplogic.com/products/maplogiclayoutmanager.html)

As another option I would not be opposed to exporting a map as a PNG and inputting it into another program to make booklets. Are there any programs that are more map centric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcMap only has one layout. You can do some tricks with hiding portions of the layout with graphics and optimize your bookmarks.

You should create your booklet in a desktop publishing software such as Adobe InDesign then place linked images into your InDesign layout. InDesign has booklet templates built in and it's really easy to customize layouts for any type of print job.  Better yet, you can design you booklet to paramters required by the print shop (CMYK vs RGB, colou profiles, bleeds, etc.)

Every time you update you map, export the maps and overwrite the older version. InDesign will recognize that the source linked image was update and prompt you to refresh the source.  For a booklet that's probably the best workflow. You will have all the graphic design power of InDesign with the possibility to link photoshop and Illustrator files and you can still update your maps in ArcMap.